# In python, given a list of lists, how do you identify the index of a matching element?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

```
>>> birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose']
>>> cats = ['tiger', 'lion']
>>> humans = ['human']
>>> at_the_zoo = [birds, cats, humans]
```

Given a list of lists like at_the_zoo, how do I locate which list tiger is in?

```
for animal in sum(at_the_zoo, []):
    if "tiger" == animal:
        print "1 help!"
```

For example, I can find tiger in the list of animals, and if I use enumerate, it will tell me it is at index 3. How do I figure out that it is part of element 1 of the list at_the_zoo.
searching for duck will tell me element 0, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the linked answer is not really a duplicate. The other question has arbitrary nesting and this is one level of nesting. The better answer to each is different. I nominate to reopen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think something like:

```
def find_element(nested_lst, what):
    for idx, sublst in enumerate(nested_lst):
        try:
            idx2 = sublst.index(what)
            return (idx, idx2)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

should work.

example:

```
>>> def find_element(nested_lst, what):
...     for idx, sublst in enumerate(nested_lst):
...         try:
...             idx2 = sublst.index(what)
...             return (idx, idx2)
...         except ValueError:
...             pass
... 
>>> birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose']
>>> cats = ['tiger', 'lion']
>>> humans = ['human']
>>> find_element([birds, cats, humans], 'human')
(2, 0)
>>> find_element([birds, cats, humans], 'gator')  # returns None if not found.
>>> find_element([birds, cats, humans], 'tiger')
(1, 0)
```

It's worth noting that on average, `list.index` is an O(N) operation which means that lists aren't the most efficient data structure for testing membership.  if your actual data supports it, it might be worthwhile to consider using a `set` instead.

Comment: Note that if all you care about is the index of the `sublst` containing `what`, and not the index of `what` within the `sublst`, you can just say `if what in sublst: return idx`, rather than using the `try`/`except` block in conjunction with `sublst.index`. It won't change the efficiency, but arguably looks a little nicer.

Comment: @dano -- Fair point.  For some reason I was under the impression that OP wanted both.

Comment: I liked this answer because it pointed to the sets data structure, which would probably be the right thing to use. The solution with the suggested edit by dano worked! :) I would edit in dano's suggestion if possible. Otherwise thanks!
In my program, I ended up sticking to lists

Answer (score 3):

Just build an index:

```
>>> birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose']
>>> cats = ['tiger', 'lion']
>>> humans = ['human']
>>> at_the_zoo = [birds, cats, humans]
>>> index = {}
>>> for i, arr in enumerate(at_the_zoo):
...   index.update(zip(arr, [i]*len(arr)))
...
>>> index
{'tiger': 1, 'goose': 0, 'lion': 1, 'human': 2, 'duck': 0, 'chicken': 0}
>>> index.get('tiger')
1
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> for i, arr in enumerate(at_the_zoo):
...   arr_len = len(arr)
...   index.update(zip(arr, zip([i]*arr_len, range(arr_len))))
...
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(index)
{'chicken': (0, 1),
 'duck': (0, 0),
 'goose': (0, 2),
 'human': (2, 0),
 'lion': (1, 1),
 'tiger': (1, 0)}
>>> index.get('tiger')
(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The two posted answers are find, but @newtover's is a bit too arcane for my tastes and @mgilson's is not answering the question as asked. Let me have a go of it.

```
def find_in_inner(lst, target):
    for i, sublst in enumerate(lst):
        if target in sublst:
            return i

>>> birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose']
>>> cats = ['tiger', 'lion']
>>> humans = ['human']
>>> at_the_zoo = [birds, cats, humans]
>>> find_in_inner(at_the_zoo, "tiger")
1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of a list of lists, if you want a tuple of the sublist number and index into that sublist, you can do:

```
[(i,j) for i, sl in enumerate(LoL) for j,e in enumerate(sl) if e==tgt]
```

Demo:

```
>>> birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose']
>>> cats = ['tiger', 'lion']
>>> humans = ['human']
>>> zoo = [birds, cats, humans]
>>> tgt='lion'
>>> [(i,j) for i, sl in enumerate(zoo) for j,e in enumerate(sl) if e==tgt]
[(1, 1)]
```

That correctly handles the potential case of multiple targets in the sublists.

If you know that you only care about the first instance, you can do:

```
[(i,sl.index(tgt)) for i, sl in enumerate(zoo) if tgt in sl]
```

If you don't care that duplicates are eliminated and you need rapid access, you can build an index:

```
{e:(i,j) for i, sl in enumerate(zoo) for j, e in enumerate(sl)}
# {'tiger': (1, 0), 'goose': (0, 2), 'lion': (1, 1), 'human': (2, 0), 'duck': (0, 0), 'chicken': (0, 1)}
```

Assume that there is in each case a human, cat and bird named 'bob':

```
birds = ['duck', 'chicken', 'goose', 'bob']
cats = ['tiger', 'lion','bob']
humans = ['human','bob']
```

You can construct an index that correctly handles multiple entries into multiple sublists this way:

```
index={}
for i, sl in enumerate(zoo):
    for j, item in enumerate(sl):
        index.setdefault(item, []).append((i,j))
```

Index becomes:

```
  {'tiger': [(1, 0)], 
   'goose': [(0, 2)], 
   'lion': [(1, 1)], 
   'human': [(2, 0)], 
   'duck': [(0, 0)], 
   'chicken': [(0, 1)], 
   'bob': [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1)]}
```